# Getting memory warning in ipad1

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have created cocos2d game. During testing i got some memory warnings, i solved all memory warnings in ipad3(New ipad) but i couldnt solve the below memory warning in ipad 1. Can you guys please help me....

1.

```
2012-08-01 22:19:16.399 Game[238:707] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file 'Animation.png' as texture
2012-08-01 22:19:16.662 Game[238:707] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file 'Ani.png' as texture
2012-08-01 22:19:16.681 Game[238:707] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file 'Faces.png' as texture
2012-08-01 22:19:16.753 Game[238:707] cocos2d: removeChildByTag: child not found!
2012-08-01 22:19:16.819 Game[238:707] Received memory warning.
```

2.

```
2012-08-01 22:23:11.573 Game[238:707] cocos2d: Received memory warning.
2012-08-01 22:23:11.573 Game[238:707] cocos2d: CCTextureCache: removing unused texture: img.jpg
2012-08-01 22:23:11.576 Game[238:707] cocos2d: CCTextureCache: removing unused texture: play.png
2012-08-01 22:23:11.582 Game[238:707] cocos2d: CCTextureCache: removing unused texture: img1.png
2012-08-01 22:23:11.585 Game[238:707] cocos2d: CCTextureCache: removing unused texture: youNeedToPopup.png
2012-08-01 22:23:11.590 Game[238:707] cocos2d: CCTextureCache: removing unused texture: popup.png
2012-08-01 22:23:11.599 Game[238:707] cocos2d: CCTextureCache: removing unused texture: conti.png
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Memory warnings are completely normal. Indeed, this is the mechanism that allow iOS to retake back used memory that can be freed and continue working without crashing.

You can observe that in Instruments Allocation tools: memory is gradually filled up; then a memory warning is sent, and you will see memory quickly to be freed (up to a point). This is the sign of a healthy application.

What you should worry about is that, when a memory warning is sent out, memory is not recovered. But then your app would promptly be killed.

So, memory warnings + app not crashing is no worry at all.

Comment: hai sergio, my game is strucking after getting memory warnings and then game is crashed (15mintes later). what is wrong in my code? can u tell me.. thanks